# Introduction of symmetries in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, symmetry, observables

The (Italian) book that I am currently reading introduces the topic of symmetries in quantum mechanics in the following way:

> Let O and O' be two distinct observers and let $A$ and $B$ be two quantities that result from certain possible operations of measurement performed by O and let $A'$ and $B'$ be the quantities resulting from the corresponding operations performed by O'.
> If we admit the perfect isotropy of physical space, then the two systems O and O' must be physically
> completely equivalent. The operators $A$ and $A'$, $B$ and $B'$ must therefore have
> the same eigenvalues: $$A \phi_r=a_r\phi_r$$ $$ B\chi_s=b_s\chi_s$$
> and: $$A' \phi'_r=a_r\phi'_r$$ $$ B'\chi'_s=b_s\chi'_s$$
> Furthermore, if at a certain instant O performed a measurement of A and observed the result A = $a_r$ and O' a measurement of A' and observed A' = $a_r$, then
> the probabilities that immediately subsequent observations of B and B' give the values ​​B = $b_s$ and B' = $b_s$ must be equal, i.e. we have:
> $$|\left< \phi_r|\chi_s\right>|^2=|\left< \phi'_r|\chi'_s\right>|^2$$
> Given the complete arbitrariness of the observables A, B, the isotropy of the
> space then translates into the statement that we can associate with every state vector
> $|f\rangle$ a second state vector $|f'\rangle$  which is
> "seen" by O' in the same way that $|f\rangle$ is "seen" by O.
> The function $\Omega:|f\rangle \rightarrow |f\rangle$ satisfies
> the equality:
> $$|\left< f|g\right>|=|\left< f'|g'\right>| . $$

So we know two things:

1. $A$ and $A'$, $B$ and $B'$ must have the same spectrum.
2. The probability of measuring $b_s$ after $a_r$is conserved.

The book seems to suggest that from these two properties we can show that:

3. For each state vector $|f⟩$ there is a second state vector $|f′⟩$ (up to the choice of a phase)
   which is "seen" by O' in the same way that $|f⟩$ is seen by O, is "seen" by O.
4. $|\left< f|g\right>|=|\left< f'|g'\right>| . $

Is my interpretation correct? If so, I do not understand how we can mathematically show that the second pair of statements is a consequence of the first two.
What does it quantitatively mean that a vector is "seen" in the same way by an observer?

Comment: Which Italian book? Which page?

Comment: Caldirola, Cirelli, Prosperi - "Introduzione alla fisica teorica" pg.552,553

Comment: 3. and 4. follow from the fact that A, and B are self-adjoint, hence their discrete spectrum eigenvectors span the pure states Hilbert space.

Comment: I already tried to write $|f⟩$ and $|f'⟩$ in terms of the basis vectors $χs$ and $χ's$ and then attempted to show that $|f⟩$ and  $|f'⟩$ had the same fourier coefficients but it didn't get me very far

Comment: [Wigner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_theorem).

Comment: In the book Wigner theorem is used, after this discussion, to state that $\Omega$ must be either unitary or anti-unitary.

Comment: The standard references for "Wigner's theorem" are: E.P. Wigner, Gruppentheorie, Vieweg, Braunschweig, 1931, p. 251-254 and V. Bargman, J. Math. Phys. 5, 1964, p.862.